# whl file does not include all the expected files

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

Good day everyone. I am fairly new to the Python experience and still have very little knowledge about all the necessary bits and pieces to have things working properly. Excuses in advance if my choice of words/terminology is not very accurate.

I expanded some python code in VisualStudio based on pre-existing scripts and I have tested by code by running it in debugging mode from VisualStudio. (The entry_points are defined in the setup.py).

This is how the setup.py looks like:

```
import setuptools
from setuptools import find_packages

import dataconversion.managers.all_manager

setuptools.setup(
    name='dataconversion',
    version='1.0',
    author='icsBO',
    author_email='redacted',
    description='redacted',
    packages=find_packages(), 
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'ConvertAll': 'run_all=all_manager.AllManager.process_all'
    }
)
```

Now it's time to export the whole project into a wheel file (or so I was told) and import it into DataBricks to get this code running with scheduled triggers at night.

I open the command prompt and I run the following:

```
C:\Dev\icsboDM\src\DataMigration>python --version 
Python 3.9.13

C:\Dev\icsboDM\src\DataMigration>pip --version 
pip 22.2.2 from C:\Users\icsbo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

C:\Dev\icsboDM\src\DataMigration>pip install setuptools wheel 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\icsbo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (63.4.1) 
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\icsbo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.37.1)

C:\Dev\icsboDM\src\DataMigration>python setup.py bdist_wheel 
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py

C:\Users\icsbo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools. 
warnings.warn( 
installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel 
running install 
running install_lib 
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel 
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\dataconversion 
copying build\lib\dataconversion\main_all.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\dataconversion 
copying build\lib\dataconversion\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\dataconversion 
running install_egg_info 
running egg_info 
writing dataconversion.egg-info\PKG-INFO 
writing dependency_links to dataconversion.egg-info\dependency_links.txt 
writing entry points to dataconversion.egg-info\entry_points.txt 
writing top-level names to dataconversion.egg-info\top_level.txt 
reading manifest file 'dataconversion.egg-info\SOURCES.txt' 
writing manifest file 'dataconversion.egg-info\SOURCES.txt' 
Copying dataconversion.egg-info to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\dataconversion-1.0-py3.9.egg-info 
running install_scripts creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\dataconversion-1.0.dist-info\WHEEL 
creating 'dist\dataconversion-1.0-py3-none-any.whl' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel' to it 
adding 'dataconversion/__init__.py' 
adding 'dataconversion/main_all.py' 
adding 'dataconversion-1.0.dist-info/METADATA' 
adding 'dataconversion-1.0.dist-info/WHEEL' 
adding 'dataconversion-1.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt' 
adding 'dataconversion-1.0.dist-info/top_level.txt' 
adding 'dataconversion-1.0.dist-info/RECORD' 
removing build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
```

At this stage I find the generated whl file in the C:\Dev\icsboDM\src\DataMigration\dist folder, but it's tiny, it has only the 5 .py files listed above, while the whole "project" in VisualStudio has several other .py files that are used.

Why is my whl incomplete? Am I clearly missing anything here?

Comment: Edit the question to show the project's directory structure. -- Most likely you are missing some `__init__.py` files in the importable packages and sub-packages. The `setuptools.find_packages()` function can only find importable packages and sub-packages if the directories and sub-directories all contain an `__init__.py` file. Those `__init__.py` files can be completely empty, but they have to be there, otherwise the directory is not considered to be an importable package and is ignored.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I do not have the __init__.py in all folders! that's why! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by other users' comments on this thread, what I was missing here was the `__init__.py` file in the various folders where my .py files are stored. I only had one `__init__.py` file in the root folder of my project, hence when trying to create the wheel file, the process was only exporting what I had in the root folder. By adding the `__init__.py` where needed has resolved my issue and I have now a complete wheel file including all files.

Comment: If by "root folder", you mean the directory containing the `setup.py` then there should not be any `__init__.py` there. Only in the directories that are supposed to be imported. I am also concerned about the `import dataconversion.managers.all_manager` in your `setup.py`. That is why I recommend you show the project's directory structure in your question, and generally why you should provide a [mre]. -- Anyway, this question is more about personalized support for your own project rather than a true Q&A useful to everyone as is the spirit of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The generated `.whl` only includes the files defined in the `packages` argument of the `setup.py`. It seems that some of the .py files that are used by your project are not included in any package that you defined.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure I understand exactly what I need to do. Does it mean I have to explicit all the >200 file names in the setup.py?  I would have expected this to be smarter and - starting from the entry points - able to find what it is required for the package to be complete... Am I completely out of the right path here?

Comment: Not by hand :) Add `MANIFEST.in` in project root folder with the following content `recursive-include dataconversion *.py` (also check if there's `__init__.py` file present in the folders (these can be empty), otherwise it won't be treated as a package. Then run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` again

Comment: Collating your reply and the comment from sinoroc above I was able to find the solution. Thank you! Now it kind of make sense to me.

Comment: please post your solution as separate answer and then mark your answer accepted. That way thread is marked "done" and there's a value for future readers